# React native app giving blank screen when rendering two RNCamera components

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to use two RNCamera components in a screen, so that each component takes half of the screen and I can show back and front camera at the same time.

But unfortunately, the app is giving just a blank screen as soon as I add the second RNCamera component. Can someone help me with this.

Below is my code.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <RNCamera
            ref={ref => {
              this.camera1 = ref;
            }}
            style={styles.preview}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Permission to use camera',
              message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
              message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
              console.log(barcodes);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <RNCamera
            ref={ref => {
              this.camera2 = ref;
            }}
            style={styles.preview}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Permission to use camera',
              message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
              message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
              console.log(barcodes);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'yellow', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using two camera instances in a single view. As it turns out the implementation of react-native-camera doesn't support it. So the only option I found was to use this [fork](https://github.com/MihaiDamian/react-native-camera) from github

Here is an [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/642#issuecomment-295402172) with a good explanation of this case.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not having any luck in implementing this based on the documentation on the fork. if you have implemneted this, can you please share the github how you did this?